# Set.union F# trouble

Tags: f#

I have a `Set<String*String>`, and I'm trying to write a function that takes all the elements of that Set and return a `Set<String>`. My idea is to use Set.fold, and have an empty set accumulator and take the union of the two sets, but I'm running into problems. Here is the code:

```
type Chart = Set<Country*Country>;;

let countriesInChart (chart : Chart) =
  Set.fold(fun (x,y) set -> Set.union [x;y] set ) chart []
```

But I get this error

```
        Set.fold(fun (x,y) set -> Set.union [x;y] set ) chart [];;
  --------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'a * 'b    
but here has type
    Set<'c>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your types and function signatures.

`Set.fold` takes a `'State -> 'T -> 'State` as the `folder` function. `'State` is the type that you're folding into and that will be the eventual return value, so in this case, you want it to be of type `Set<Country>`.

That means your lambda can't be right, because the first argument is a tuple. So we should probably switch the arguments of that lambda:

```
let countriesInChart (chart : Chart) =
    Set.fold(fun set (x,y) -> Set.union [x;y] set ) chart []
```

Compiling that gives us

```
(96,39): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    Set<'a>
but here has type
    'b list
```

(96,39) in this case is the `Set.union` function, and of course that is not used correctly, because it requires two sets, but we're passing it one set and a list. We can create a set from the list using `Set.ofList`:

```
let countriesInChart (chart : Chart) =
    Set.fold(fun set (x,y) -> [x; y] |> Set.ofList |> Set.union set) chart []
```

Again, we're getting a different error, so we're probably making progress:

```
(96,80): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    Set<(Country * Country) * (Country * Country)>
but here has type
    'a list
```

(96,80) is the empty list at the end of the line - and of course, that's wrong, because the third argument to `Set.fold` needs to be `Set<'T>`. The set replacement for an empty list would be `Set.empty`, so let's go with that:

```
let countriesInChart (chart : Chart) =
    Set.fold(fun set (x,y) -> [x; y] |> Set.ofList |> Set.union set) chart Set.empty
```

It compiles! But as you found, it returns `Set<Country * Country>` instead of just `Set<Country>`.

Cases like this are when type inference makes it a little harder to see what's going on, so we should go ahead and add type annotations where we know exactly what the types need to be. The most obvious place is the return type of the function:

```
let countriesInChart (chart : Chart) : Set<Country> =
    Set.fold(fun set (x,y) -> [x; y] |> Set.ofList |> Set.union set) chart Set.empty
```

Now the error is:

```
(96,74): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    Set<Country>    
but given a
    Chart    
The type 'Country' does not match the type 'Country * Country'
```

That error is for the second argument of `Set.fold`, and the reason is that once again, the arguments are in the wrong order. The signature of `Set.fold` is `('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> Set<'T> -> 'State`. If we look at what we already have, `'State` in this case is `Set<Country>`, and `'T` is `Country * Country`. That means `Set.empty` needs to be the second and `chart` the last argument, and so we arrive at

```
let countriesInChart (chart : Chart) =
    Set.fold(fun set (x,y) -> [x; y] |> Set.ofList |> Set.union set) Set.empty chart
```

The most important rule of functional programming is this: Let the types guide you! ;-)

Comment: I tried doing that and although it compiled, it returns Set<Country * Country>

Comment: You have the last two parameters for the `fold` backwards, they should be `Set.empty chart`.

Comment: Yep, found that quickly, after I actually fired up Visual Studio to get into this. :-) Answer updated and expanded.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev Thank you so much for the clear explanation, helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
let f (chart: Chart) =
  Set.fold (fun (x:Set<string>) (a,b) -> x |> Set.add a |> Set.add b) Set.empty chart
```

I'm not sure if the type annotation is necessary but it does force the output to be a `Set<string>`.