# Creating a set within a set F#

Tags: f#

Say I have an empty Set. I want to create multiple sets of strings inside that set. How would I go about doing that?

For example, I'm trying to write a function that takes as parameters, a `Set<String*String>`, a `Set<String>` and a `Set<String>`, and returns a `Set<Set<String>>`.

```
type Country = string;;
type Chart = Set<Country*Country>;;
type Colour = Set<Country>;;
type Colouring = Set<Colour>;;
```

The function is:

```
let rec extColouring (chart: Chart) (colours : Colouring) (country : Country) =
```

And the value of the function should be:

```
(*
val extColouring :
  chart:Chart -> colours:Colouring -> country:Country -> Set<Set<Country>>
*)
```

For example, a chart would be like

```
val myWorld : Chart =
  set
    [("Andorra", "Benin"); ("Andorra", "Canada"); ("Andorra", "Denmark");
     ("Benin", "Canada"); ("Benin", "Denmark"); ("Canada", "Denmark");
     ("Estonia", "Canada"); ("Estonia", "Denmark"); ("Estonia", "Finland");
     ...]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlfow. In the past few days various questions on this problem have been asked and answered here. Take a look at the previous questions for the [F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23) tag. Also you need attempt a solution and explain where you are having problems before most of us will answer. You did not post any attempt or code for us to review.

Comment: See: [F# map colouring troubles](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35401471/1243762), 
[Trouble with Set.forall F#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35399564/1243762), 
[Set.union F# trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35400728/1243762), 
[What am I doing wrong with Set.Fold F#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35276324/1243762)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: And this is pretty clearly homework, that a lot of people are asking about. The professor is probably aware of it by now.

Comment: Indeed, it is not necessarily a bad thing, as long as you aren't asking people to just do the problem for you.

Comment: @jackmott For all we know, rondoe is the instructor and he is checking up on the conduct of us here who represent F#. If we give out to many answers with out teaching the students, then he just might ban the class from using StackOverflow.

Comment: So, as this set of questions piqued my interest, I dug in, and apparently the set of questions boils down to:  reimplement (more or less) http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/courses/02157/2012/mapColouring.fsx but using set instead of list?  (and the original code is quite fugly, may I add)

Comment: The word "fugly" is a portmanteau of a word that starts with F and the word ugly. functions like the one shown above with "ext" in front of it (giving the developer no clue as to what it means or the intent of the function) (also Colour as a collection of Country and then Colouring as a collection of Colour).  I get that this is the "four color map" problem, but a lot of the code looks like somebody ported it from C.

Comment: @Guy Coder I've authored books, too. And I've published fugly code in them.

Comment: The course [COMP 302](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~prakash/Courses/Comp302/Admin/outline.pdf) is being taught at McGill this semester by [Prakash Panangaden](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~prakash/) - [Problems](http://cs.mcgill.ca/~prakash/Courses/Comp302/)

Comment: Your question has been resolved?